# Migrating from Google OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect with different redirect_uri and openid.realm parameters

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, acs, google-openid, openid-connect

I am migrating from Google OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect. I am currently using [Microsofts ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147631.aspx) which uses Googles depreciated OpenID 2.0 for authentication. This means my realm was automatically set to 'https://mywebsite.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/openid'.

ACS has no plans to upgrade so I have begun integrating with Google OpenID Connect directly. I'm following [Googles migration documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?#adjust-uri) which says I can add a  `openid.realm` parameter (set as the realm used for OpenID 2.0) to then obtain the openid_id needed to map existing user accounts. Also it says the `redirect_uri` **needs to be the same** as the `openid.realm`. I guess for security reasons.

So my problem is I cannot set the redirect uri to the same as the realm because the realm is the ACS endpoint e.g.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=id.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%3A2018%2F&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=state&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.accesscontrol.windows.net%3A443%2Fv2%2Fopenid
```

I have tried setting them different but I get an error

> 'Realm didn't match redirect_uri/origin. Error code: 5'

Is Google planning to support cases like this?

Any ideas on ways to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case it still matters, I think the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#adjust-uri) actually say:

"Find your application's `redirect_uri` and change it (if necessary) so that it matches your OpenID 2.0 `openid.realm` value, **according to the matching rules** in [section 9.2 of the OpenID 2.0 spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#realms)"

That boils down to the domain matching and the `redirect_uri` being a sub-path of the path in the `openid.realm`, if there is one.

Since your `openid.realm` included a path I think you're kind of screwed and you will have to resort to setting up some kind of redirection in your server to map the old `redirect_url` to your new path. Thankfully, in my case, I can set the `redirect_url` to any new path as my `openid.realm` only had a domain name.